# Drag elements into a droppable list, into the proper position

Tags: jquery, list, droppable

Is there any way to drag elements onto a sortable (droppable) list?  And have them added into the proper position in the list?

At first I thought I could just do this with a function using a droppable div under the list BUT my lists will get longer than the screen.  Meaning users will have to scroll and at this point, I think trying to get mouse position will be meaningless.

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to do: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tvance929/E7DPk/2/

Comment: Certainly there is, but the latter part in not clear for me (especially what 'proper' means).  Could you make a JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: Oh man, this might be my answer!  Is there an event after it's put into the new list so I can change the html of that LI?

Comment: Yeah it's the `receive` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `connectToSortable` and set the `helper` to `clone`, something like:

```
$("#theList").sortable({
    revert: true
});
$( "#dragMe" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#theList",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

See here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7DPk/6/)

Comment: The only problem I currently have with this solution (thank you very much by the way) is that my draggables need to stay in my left toolbox.  I was using the clone feature and I cannot seem to get helper clone to work with a sortable...

Comment: Ah check my updated fiddle and code, there's an easier way using `draggable` :)

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help :)